# Conformance Mode and Multiple Inheritance with Nested Templates in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, namespaces, multiple-inheritance

I'm experiencing (what appears to me as) strange behaviour from Visual Studio when trying to check whether one class is derived from another. Consider the following samples:

**Sample 1**

```
namespace X
{
    namespace Y
    {
        struct A {};
        struct B {};
    }
}

struct AB : public X::Y::A, public X::Y::B {};

static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<X::Y::A, AB>); // (1)
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<X::Y::B, AB>); // (2)
```

**Sample 2**

```
namespace X
{
    namespace Y
    {
        struct A {};
        struct B {};
    }
}

using namespace X::Y;
struct AB : public A, public B {};

static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<A, AB>); // (3)
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B, AB>); // (4)
```

I've added the `/std:c++latest` option in Visual Studio, so to my understanding, nested namespaces should be fine.

If I set the [Conformance Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance) in Visual Studio to *No*, then all the `static_assert` expressions above are satisfied.

However, if I set it to *Yes* (i.e. `/permissive-`), then (3) is satisfied but  all of (1), (2), and (4) fail. I'd appreciate any insight anyone can give into why this should be the case - is it my understanding at fault, or is it a VS issue? In particular, the fact that (3) and (4) can (and do!) differ is very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense wrongly marks them as failed but if you try to build the project it will compile successfully.

Intellisense is not a full featured compiler, it may not be as accurate or may not be updated to support the latest language features and sometimes disagrees with the compiler.